# Как использовать список цветов, чтобы цвета менялись при каждой интерации цикла?

Tags: python, list

Я начинающий программист на Pydroid 3 и учусь программировать на Python 3.9. Хочу узнать, как использовать список цветов `colors = ['red','green','blue','yellow','purple','black']`, чтобы цвета менялись при каждой итерации цикла `for` либо `while`. Как это сделать?
Примечание: *это нужно для Python Turtle Graphics.*

Comment: И всё же непонятно, при чём тут `Turtle`

Comment: @CrazyElf А при том, что я хочу сделать типо шестиугольную спираль, каждая линия которой будет своего цвета и это при помощи цикла `for`.

Comment: Ну, я вам написал в ответе как ротировать цвета. Если вам непонятно именно как рисовать спираль в `Turtle`, то и вопрос нужно было задавать именно про это. Только не меняйте текущий вопрос, а задавайте лучше новый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего использовать библиотечную функцию `itertools.cycle`:

```py
from itertools import cycle

colors = ['red','green','blue','yellow','purple','black']
for i, col in enumerate(cycle(colors)):
    print(i, col)
    if i > 20:
        break
```

Вывод:

```
0 red
1 green
2 blue
3 yellow
4 purple
5 black
6 red
7 green
8 blue
9 yellow
10 purple
11 black
12 red
13 green
14 blue
15 yellow
16 purple
17 black
18 red
19 green
20 blue
21 yellow
```

Хотя тоже самое можно в принципе сделать с помощью среза и остатка от деления по модулю.